# NullReferenceException was unhandeled

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am making a windows form application where I am adding a `PictureBox` dynamically.  What could be causing the following error?

> NullReferenceException was unhandled.
>
> Use "new" keyword to create an object of instance

Code:

```
PictureBox[] picArray = new PictureBox[allFiles.Length];
int y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < picArray.Length; i++ )
{
    this.Controls.Add(picArray[i]);
    if(i%3 == 0){
        y = y + 150;
    }
    picArray[i].Location = new Point(i*120 + 20 , y);
    picArray[i].Size = new Size(100, 200);
    picArray[i].Image = Image.FromFile(allFiles[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have initialized the array, not the `PictureBoxes` in it:

```
// all PictureBoxes in the array are null after the next statement:
PictureBox[] picArray = new PictureBox[allFiles.Length]; 
int y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < picArray.Length; i++ )
{
    var newPictureBox = new PictureBox(); // this will initialize it 
    picArray[i] = newPictureBox;  // this will add it to the array 
    this.Controls.Add(newPictureBox);
    if(i%3 == 0){
        y = y + 150;
    }
    newPictureBox.Location = new Point(i*120 + 20 , y);
    newPictureBox.Size = new Size(100, 200);
    newPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(allFiles[i]);
}
```